# Reading data types from a table and run Alter table statement without locking table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using the below function to determine the field data types from whichever table is given in the function parameter.  Basically the function reads the data type from the table and compares it to what it should be based on the "FieldDataTypes" table.  If it doesn't match, then I would like to run an Alter table SQL statement as shown below.  However I am realizing that once I open the recordset I am unable to alter the table.  When I run the Sub/Function below I get the error:

The database could not lock table "TEST TABLE" because it is already in use by another person or process.  3211.

How can I get around this so that I can loop through the fields and still alter the data types as necessary?

Thanks,

Charlie

```
Sub TestReFormat()

    FncFormatFields ("TEST TABLE")


    End Sub



    Public Function FncFormatFields(strTableName As String)

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fld As Field
    Dim strFieldName As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim intDataType As Integer
    Dim intDataTypeCheck As Integer

    On Error GoTo FormatFieldsErr:

    rstSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & strTableName & "]"

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strTableName)
        For Each fld In rst.Fields
            strFieldName = fld.Name
            intDataType = fld.Type
            Debug.Print strFieldName & " " & intDataType

            intDataTypeCheck = DLookup("DataTypeInt", "FieldDataTypes", "[FieldName] = '" & strFieldName & "'")
            Debug.Print intDataTypeCheck
                If intDataTypeCheck <> intDataType Then
                    strSQL = "ALTER TABLE [" & strTableName & "] ALTER COLUMN [" & strFieldName & "] " & intDataTypeCheck & ""
                    DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)
                End If

    Continue2428:
        Next fld

    Exit Function

    FormatFieldsErr:
        If Err.Number = 2428 Then
            Resume Continue2428
        Else
            MsgBox Err.Description & " " & Err.Number
        End If

    End Function
```

Comment: Since you have no interest in the data in the recordset, perhaps a [`TableDef`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195790.aspx) object might provide the structure of the table without preventing you from running the `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Comment: Hi Zev, I've never worked with TableDef objects.  How would that work?

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48459778/111794).

Answer (score 2):

Break your function into two parts:

1. A Function that examines the table returns a SQL array of ALTER TABLE statements
2. A Function that executes the SQL array

The query that locks the table in 1) will be closed, allowing you to alter it in 2) without error.

PS: Use `rstSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [" & strTableName & "]"` so you don't waste resources returning multiple rows.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines, except that I would have recommended using a `Collection` instead of an array.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any need to return any rows at all; just examining the structure of a table can be done using [`TableDef`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195790.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can update data in a table without locking. In fact FEW know that the Access database engine JET/ACE can even update columns in records that are currently in use and dirty by other users (the update has to be specific to the one column - this is possible in some cases).

However, to modify a table structure and data type? You will require full exclusive rights and other users cannot have the table open, and you need full lock rights to the whole database.

Answer (score 0):

Since in this case the data is of no interest, only the table structure, you can use a [`TableDef`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195790.aspx) object to get the table structure; this will get around the lock:

```
Public Function FncFormatFields(tablename As String)
Dim dbs As Database, tdf As TableDef, fld As Field
On Error GoTo FormatFieldsErr:

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set tdf = dbs.TableDefs(tablename)
For Each fld In tdf.Fields
    Dim fieldname As String
    fieldname = fld.Name
    Dim datatype As Integer
    datatype = fld.Type
    Debug.Print fieldname & " " & datatype

    Dim finalDatatype As Integer
    finalDatatype = DLookup("DataTypeInt", "FieldDataTypes", "[FieldName] = '" & fieldname & "'")
    Debug.Print finalDatatype

    If datatype <> finalDatatype Then DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE [" & tablename & "] ALTER COLUMN [" & fieldname & "] " & finalDatatype & ""
Next

Continue2428:
    Next fld

Exit Function

FormatFieldsErr:
    If Err.Number = 2428 Then Resume Continue2428
    MsgBox Err.Description & " " & Err.Number
End Function
```

Even if the data is of interest, `TableDef` has an `OpenRecordset` method that returns the data in the table.

It might also be possible to use a snapshot-type recordset, which doesn't have an open connection to the database, and therefore shouldn't be affected by the lock. (I didn't test this.)

Note: I've only tested this with an `.accdb`; if this works as well with an `.mdb` that would be good to know.